# Cannot Build JemmyFX for JDK11 - class "com.sun.glass.ui.Robot" not longer existing

Tags: java, javafx, jemmyfx, openjdk-11

In my project I'm using JemmyFX to test my JavaFX-UI.
Now I will update from Java8 to Java11. Because of an exception in my `TestRun` I have also to update my JemmyFX-Version.

So I tried to check out the JemmyFX-Stuff from openjfx ("http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx"). After setting the correct dependencies (JemmyCore and new JavaFX-Packages) one problem still remaining:

The class `com.sun.glass.ui.Robot` is not longer available.

Has anyone an idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

[`Robot`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/robot/Robot.html) has been moved to public API since 11 and the internal class you specified [has been removed](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/pull/36/files?file-filters[]=). Use the public class instead. If the dependency was not updated for JavaFX 11, you can build an updated version yourself.